# Why is my unspayed cat trying to chase off my other cat that has kittens?

Tags: cats, behavior, breeding, socializing

I have a cat that is unspayed, about 1 year old. She has been sleeping next to my other cat, who has kittens about 10 days old, to the point the mother is constantly having to move the kittens. She is currently hiding in a drawer in our bathroom, but my other cat is now attempting to force the drawer open.

How can I stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 2):

As to the question in your title, she is doing so, because your mother cat is her friend. But the problem is, your mother cat has "moved on" and "settled down", she no longer has time for the party life of carefree snuggles; she is mostly concerned with her kittens.

I can think of three solutions:

1. Try to shower the non-mother cat with as much love and affection as you can to fill the gap left by your mother cat
2. Get her another cat friend, although, as you may know, this could easily go wrong and the new cat might not get along with either of your existing cats
3. I would be very hesitant of this third option as there are already so many cats without homes, but if she was also had kittens of her own, that may keep her more occupied and she would not have to bother your other cat